# Ionic/Cordova app on Windows 10 tablet: keyboard not working

Tags: angularjs, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

I'll try to be short. I have a Ionic/Cordova hybrid app running on Android, but now I have to make it run on a Windows 10 tablet. The problem is that the keyboard is not working, it does not open. I forced it to open with code, but even so, no success at all.

I am following this post to build the app:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/07/29/targeting-windows-10-with-your-apache-cordova-app.aspx

The Visual Studio and every other components are perfectly installed. It's definitely not a problem with the dev environment. I'm thinking that the problem might be with the Windows 10 platform, when I change the platform to Windows 8.1 and build the app, the keyboard shows just fine. When I turn it back to Windows 10, the keyboard vanishes forever. To build the app on top of the Windows 8.1 makes the app to crash in several parts from CSS to Javascript. jQuery, AngularJs. Everything just stops working thanks to the IE based webview.

So I think that the problem is a bug in the Windows 10 platform for ionic/cordova. You can add a platform with Visual Studio or just use the command line:

ionic platform add "windows@https://aka.ms/cordova-win10"

I've be googling around, but it seens that no one is having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an issue in Windows 10 OS build, which should be fixed in an update:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9711

Upd: This is fixed in Windows 10 OS Build 10586.17, Version 1511.

Comment: That sounds great! Is there any development version with this fix that I can use just for now? Or a release date maybe?

Comment: I believe it's better to ask MS support about this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/tablet-mode-in-windows-10-no-virtual-keyboard/e28f00d7-031f-412c-91f5-6677753eb3fb?page=1

Comment: I misunderstood the problem. I thought it was a fix for the Apache Cordova, but it's for Windows 10! Wonderful MS don't you think? So I've been looking and turns out that I have two different Win 10 versions: the RTM and the 1511. MS has two different patches for each version: KB3105213 for the RTM and KB3105211 for the 1511. The versions with RTM, patch included, still have the bug, the keyboard doesn't open. The 1511 version, patch included, solves the problem and the keyboard works normally as expected. So the solution for now is to use the 1511 version with at least the KB3105211 update.